# When was Civilization 2 released?

Tags: civilization-2

When was Civilization 2 released?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_II), February 29, 1996 for the PC version and January 20, 1998 for Playstation version.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that there were also a Playstation version.

Comment: I didn't know either until I read the Wikipedia article.

Comment: It was also re-released in 2002 for newer Operating Systems.